# If we are importing a data from MySql to HDFS by using Sqoop, what would be the file format which has stored in HDFS?

Tags: hadoop

If we are importing a data from MySql to HDFS by using Sqoop, what would be the file format which has stored in HDFS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sqoop has imported your data as comma-separated text files. It supports a number of other file formats, which can be activated with the arguments listed below

mSqoop arguments that control the file formats of import commands
Argument

```
--as-avrodatafile    Data is imported as Avro files.

--as-sequencefile    Data is imported as Sequence Files.

--as-textfile       The default file format, with imported data as CSV text files.

example: you should pass like below.

 sqoop import  mysql:--/--/db   --as-avrodatafile
```

Answer (score 0):

When importing a table from **MySQL to HDFS using Sqoop**, table data will be stored in `/user/hadoop-username/tablename` folder. It will contain 2 files named `_SUCCESS` and `part-m-00000`, one directory named `_logs`.

The actual table data will be stored in `part-m-00000`. Most probably, it will be `comma delimited` file.

If you want to query the table using hadoop, its better to use **Hive** instead of HDFS. Just **import using sqoop from MySQL to Hive** so that you can query the table using hive command line in future.